# Moving average in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, moving-average

I am trying to figure out how to get moving average from a certain value I receive from my microphone. I have a `frequencyChangedWithValue` function calling my measuring method. This means that I get a changing value of frequency up to 10 times in a second. I am interested now how to make an average number from all of these changing values. How do I do it?

#### Code

```
- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    self.currentFrequency = newFrequency;

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(filterFrequencyToGetBeats) withObject:nil];
    [pool drain];
    pool = nil;
}


- (void) filterFrequencyToGetBeats {

    if (self.currentFrequency > 1000 && pointInTime % 2 == 0)
    {
        tm_start = mach_absolute_time();
        pointInTime = pointInTime + 1;
    }
    else
        if (self.currentFrequency > 1000 && pointInTime % 2 == 1)
        {
            pointInTime = pointInTime + 1;

            tm_end = mach_absolute_time();
            tm_elapsed = tm_end - tm_start;
            mach_timebase_info(&info);
            tm_nanoSeconds = tm_elapsed * info.numer / info.denom;
            tm_milliSeconds = tm_nanoSeconds / (1000000);
            tm_seconds = (tm_milliSeconds/1000);

            fflush(stdout);
            printf ( "| allocateAudio: %5lld milliseconds, (%12lld nano seconds)\n",     tm_milliSeconds, tm_nanoSeconds );
        }
    }
```

Comment: See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8447868/456851

Comment: As you're not using ARC, in this case pool=nil is useless.

Comment: There is a very comprehensive [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) on this topic.  Generally, lacking some reason to the contrary, you'd use an [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).  The code is so simple that there's no need crib it from somewhere.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - But often good practice, nonetheless.

Comment: For how I see it it's more a redundancy than a good practice.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - You must not maintain old code.

Answer (score 3):

I have one of these:

```
// MovingAverage.h

@interface MovingAverage : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic) float movingAverage;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) float cumulativeAverage;

- (id)initWithPeriod:(NSUInteger)period;
- (void)addDatum:(NSNumber *)datum;

@end


// MovingAverage.m

#import "MovingAverage.h"

@interface MovingAverage ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *queue;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger period;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger count;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float movingAverage;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float cumulativeAverage;
@end

@implementation MovingAverage

- (id)initWithPeriod:(NSUInteger)period {

    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _period = period;
        // with arc
        _queue = [NSMutableArray array];
        // without arc
        _queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addDatum:(NSNumber *)datum {

    [self.queue insertObject:datum atIndex:0];

    float removed = 0;
    float datumf = [datum floatValue];

    if (self.queue.count > self.period) {
        removed = [[self.queue lastObject] floatValue];
        [self.queue removeLastObject];
    }

    self.movingAverage = self.movingAverage - (removed / self.period) + (datumf / self.period);

    // compute the cumulative average
    self.cumulativeAverage = self.cumulativeAverage + (datumf - self.cumulativeAverage) / ++self.count;
}

// if non-ARC
- (void)dealloc {
    [_queue release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think you may need to initialise your queue (NSMutableArray) somewhere in your constructor.

Comment: Good point.  I have a lazy init in the getter which I didn't paste here.  Will add to init.

Comment: Ok but for non-Arc, you are releasing the Queue in the dealloc (which is good to me) but it is actually not retained when created. You may want to consider:

 _queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_period];

instead of

_queue = [NSMutableArray array]

Comment: right again.  i forgot i had the non-arc option at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by holding an array and a total count of elements. Since it's a moving average, the elements count may be higher than the total count of array elements, and you need to compute the remainder of this count.

For example:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* elements;   
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSUInteger lastIndex;
@property (nonatomic,assign) double average;
```

Initialize elements and make it hold N values (NSNumber's of long values). You should be able to change the average just by calling a simple method like this one:

```
- (void) changeAverage: (long) newValue
{
    NSUInteger index= (++lastIndex) % elements.count;
    NSNumber* oldValue= elements[index]; // same as [elements objectAtIndex: index];
    average+= (double)newValue/elements.count -  (double)[oldValue longValue]/elements.count;   
    // The cast is to don't lose the decimal precision while dividing these numbers.
    [elements replaceObjectAtIndex: index withObject: @(newValue)];  
    // @(newValue) is the same as [NSNumber numberWithLong: newValue];
}
```